# akka.net only restart single routee in a pool

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net

I have a RoundRobinPool for which I want OneForOneStategy to be used so that when a child throws only that child gets restarted. I'm creating the router like this:

```
var strat = new OneForOneStrategy(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), e => Directive.Restart);

var props = Props.Create<ThrowAlwaysActor>()
                        .WithRouter(new RoundRobinPool(2))
                        .WithSupervisorStrategy(strat);

var router = system.ActorOf(props, "myrouter");
router.Tell("1");
```

output:

```
akka://loadSystem/user/myrouter/$b PRERESTART <-- pool init
akka://loadSystem/user/myrouter/$a PRERESTART <-- pool init
akka://loadSystem/user/myrouter/$a OnReceive()
[ERROR][8/21/2016 8:21:02 AM][Thread 0004][akka://loadSystem/user/myrouter] The method or operation is not implemented.
akka://loadSystem/user/myrouter/$a PRERESTART <-- the actor that threw is being restarted
akka://loadSystem/user/myrouter/$b PRERESTART <-- this actor should not be restarted
```

How to configure a RoundRobin pool to only restart the routee that threw the exception and avoid the whole pool getting restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must pass the strategy to the constructor of the pool instead of fluent Props builder:

```
var routerStrat = new OneForOneStrategy(-1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), e => Directive.Restart);

var props = Props.Create<ThrowAlwaysActor>()
                        .WithRouter(new RoundRobinPool(2, resizer, routerStrat, null));
```